# Using COLLECT and COLLECT AGGREGATE to search large dataset in ArangoDB

Tags: performance, graph, aql

I want to improve performance on some custom queries, the objective is to update group with most users daily.
It's a large dataset composed of 3 main collections:

- Users (document)
- Groups (document)
- Connections (edges)

Users can participate in many groups (1:N).
Groups can have many participants (N:1), witch are users or other groups. Ex: Fighter1 is in RaidParty1 and RaidParty1 is in Guild1.

```
 COLLECT party= user.partyID WITH COUNT INTO num_users
    SORT num_users DESC
    RETURN {"Party": party,
            "Num. Users" : num_users}
```

This takes 4 ms in the sample dataset, over a second on complete dataset, and is very memmory intensive.

I understand I could use something like

```
FOR user IN userSample
 COLLECT party= user.partyID WITH COUNT INTO num_users
 COLLECT AGGREGATE max_num_users= MAX(num_users)
   RETURN {"Top Guild": max_num_users}
```

But this isn't unsing the aggregate optimization, as forming the num_users every time is the time consuming part. Is there a way to collect and aggregate at the same time?

BONUS: Any ideia how to make it a top 10 list?

Comment: Can you share the whole query that you want to optimize, together with its explain output? A top 10 list should be easily doable by using sort + limit.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `WITH COUNT INTO` with an `AGGREGATE` clause:

```
FOR user IN userSample
  COLLECT party = user.partyID AGGREGATE num_users = LENGTH(1)
  SORT num_users DESC
  RETURN {
    "Party": party,
    "Num. Users": num_users
  }
```

However, both variants lead to the exact same execution plan (at least in the latest version of ArangoDB).

If I understand correctly, then you want to count the number of users per party and then find the maximum among these counts. This isn't possible with a single `COLLECT` operation:

> an aggregate expression must not refer to variables introduced by the COLLECT itself

[Grouping and aggregation with COLLECT in AQL | ArangoDB Documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-collect.html#aggregation:%7E:text=an%20aggregate%20expression%20must%20not%20refer%20to%20variables%20introduced%20by%20the%20COLLECT%20itself)

For a top 10 list, this should work:

```
FOR user IN userSample
  COLLECT party = user.partyID WITH COUNT INTO num_users
  SORT num_users DESC
  LIMIT 10
  RETURN {
    "Party": party,
    "Num. Users": num_users
  }
```

Comment: In my implementation both strategies lead to the exact same execution plan as well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: continuation: The optimizations I found were to index partyID and limit my search only to the known top 100 list. This way the top10 can be updated daily and top100 runs once a week in a internal copy of the DB. Thanks for your time.